# Displaying table data on a page

Tags: database

I would like to present content from a table located in Wordpress data base to a Wordpress page.
Is there any plugin that i can use.If not,what is the simplest way to code it?
Thanks,
Ron

Answer (score 1):

Had you looked into [plugins tagged "table" in official repository](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/table)?

As for coding it by hand it should not be too complex, use [`$wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) to query database and loop/output results with HTML table markup.

Comment: Thanks Rarst,
Where should i put the syntax ? i.e. i have the SQL but where should i put it in?
Can i write it on the HTML editor of a regular page or somewhere else?
Thanks,
Ron

Comment: @ron if you only need it on single page, I'd make [custom page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates), PHP code won't work in editor (unless you install plugin for that, which is usually overkill). Otherwise you can place code in `functions.php` of your theme or create simple plugin to hold it. So really - it depends, many ways to do it.